# How to disable register button and change text in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to disable register button and change text to "Please wait..." after user click register button. I tried using javascript like,

HTML,

```
<button id="disable-submit" type="submit" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-light rounded-pill" data-sitekey="{{ config('services.recaptcha.sitekey') }}" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit'>
                    {{ __('Register') }}
                </button>
```

js,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // $(document).ready(function() 
        (function(){
            $('#disable-submit').on('submit', function(){
                var btnd = $('#disable-submit');
                btnd.prop('disabled', true);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    btnd.prop('disabled', false);
                }, 5000);
            })
        })();
    </script>
```

Now it disables for a second and gets re-enable. I think it re-enables because of validation checks. I need to disable the button for 4-5 seconds, my registration process needs that much time.

Comment: "_I want to disable register button and change text to "Please wait..." after user click register button._" How is the user supposed to click the button if it's disabled?

Comment: @brombeer Please check question, I asked for disable after clicking register button

Comment: Is the form submitted via Ajax?

Comment: No, not using ajax

Comment: So ... clicking the button will submit the form/reload the page, right?!

Comment: yes, it reloads

Comment: Prevent default form submission, wait 4-5 seconds, submit the form via Javascript/Ajax

Comment: Is there any easy way, I have added controller code also to question. Please check it.

Comment: If you want a dynamic frontend your need to send the POST by ajax. brombeer is right. If you click on a button, the page starts reloading with a POST request and there for cancels the jquery event. Your need both event to be async. Ajax is the only way for your setup to work. You can use the success part of the ajax request to remove the message and relocate the user after the request is done loading.